# Fixed Parts of page: Header, Content and Footer

Tags: html, header, footer

I need 3 parts: Header, Content and footer for my page in fixed position.

```
<body>

<div id="header">
  <div id="info">
    <span id="fa">test</span>
    <br>
    <span id="en">Honey Koohpayeh Official Website</span>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="section">
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img class="img" src="img/img1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  Copyright © W3Schools.com
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
}

#section {
  padding:10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#footer {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  clear:both;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
}
```

And I'm using java script having two pictures which pic one loads at first then a loading.gif shows and then the second pic shows up.
The problem is when i show the loading, and then show the second pic, the content get empty for a sec and my footer reaches to the header. I need the three parts fixed position and nothing can changes their height. And i wanna use % like header and footer get 20% and the content gets the rest.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set a fixed height and width while the image loads and remove it when the image is received.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How?